# Is there a single catch-all-failures hook in c++?

Tags: c++, error-handling

I want that when and if the program will fail than it will be caught at this handler in order to do some guard notifications.

Is there a bottom handler or list of handlers that I need to register in order to be sure that a program cannot crash without passing through my handler?

Running on ubuntu and solution needed only to ubuntu
I need all kind of failure like exception memory allocation ...

Comment: would a shell script that re-launch the program when it's killed (whatever the reason) be an acceptable approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is that there is **no** single point where you can handle all errors in the program. You can add a `try/catch (...)` at in `main` to handle exceptions that occur after `main` is entered and before it completes. You can also add a handler for `terminate` in C++. Then depending on the OS you will also need to handle other situations differently (invalid memory references can be handled in unix/linux by handling SIG_SEGV, but that will not work in Windows --AFAIK; some other errors might trigger different signals that could or not be handled...) Further than that, there might be errors that still get unnoticed (say an invalid memory access that happens to hit a valid memory address... the program will be incorrect, but the error might go undetected)

Answer (score 2):

C++ does not run in a virtual sandbox, thus there is nothing built-in to the language to catch this. You can certainly build one yourself (for example using exceptions), but it's up to your code to construct this from the foundation up.

The platform you're running on may have something you can use though. For example in Windows there is [`SetUnhandledExceptionFilter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680634%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Of course all of this still depends on what it means to "crash".

Answer (score 2):

On process startup, call `fork`. Use the parent to monitor the child. If it encounters a fatal error, the process will go away. You can detect this and do whatever you need to do when that happens. If the child wishes to terminate normally, it can simply kill its parent before terminating.

Comment: +1, although I'd rather use the process exit value to determine normal/abnormal shutdown instead of killing the parent

Answer (score 2):

For a normal program exit you can register a handler with [`std::atexit()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/atexit).

For a program exit because of [uncaught exceptions/...](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/terminate) you can register a handler with [`std::set_terminate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/set_terminate). If by "exception memory allocation" you mean a `std::bad_alloc` exception, than this handler should be triggered.

Answer (score 1):

In Linux You need to respond to `SIGABRT` Signal. Your `callback` will be called whenever your app gets SIGABRT signal

```
signal(SIGABRT, &callback);
```

There are different Signals for different Scenarios such as `SIGSEGV`, `SIGBUS` that you ned to hook. you better hook them in different callbacks and check which error goes into what. because one error might come due to multiple problems.

Comment: Don't forget `SIGSEGV` for segfaults.

Comment: And `SIGILL` and `SIGBUS` -- other than that, perfectly correct.

Comment: Will it cover memory failure ?

Comment: Yes You will need to set Callback for SIGNALs you want to hook. and If `memory failure` causes some Signal you re hooking It will cover memory failures too. you will get `SIGSEGV` most of the time for exception and memory failures. Its better to do some tests to check which gets into what callback

Comment: Sorry, my bad... that function was `is_computer_on_fire()`. But again, suppose you get a positive result from that one, what could you do against it?  :-)

Answer (score 0):

No. If the process is `kill`ed with a `SIGKILL`, for example, no handler will be run.

P.S. FYI, this has nothing to do with the [SPOF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_point_of_failure).

Comment: @cHao: I believe there was a previous version where `SIGKILL` was not mentioned. Removing the comment as it no longer applies.

Answer (score 0):

You can put a `try`/`catch(...)` block at the top level to catch all exceptions. But there are other ways for the program to be terminated and the ways of catching these aren't portable. On Unix-based systems you'll have to create signal handlers but even those won't stop `kill -9`.

Comment: Try-catch handle only exceptions not failures

Comment: For `try`/`catch`, you also have to put those around each thread that gets created.